# MQ Listener Performance

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq

I am building Docker Containers which have a war file running on Jetty, and I have been alternating a few settings to see if performance improves but nothing so far. Per container it has been achieving 7 tps.

The settings are

```
<bean id="cachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="MQConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
</bean>


<bean id="requestQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${queuemanager}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="${incoming.queue}"/>
</bean>


<integration:poller id="poller" default="true" fixed-delay="1000" error-channel="errorChannel"/>
```

How can I improve the number of threads processing over here?

Also, my connection factory details are as shown below

```
@Bean(name="DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory provideJmsListenerContainerFactory(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());     
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    factory.setConcurrency(jmsConcurrency);
    factory.setCacheLevel(jmsCacheLevel);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true); 

    return factory;
}


 @Bean(name = "txManager")
 public PlatformTransactionManager provideTransactionManager() {         
     return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory());
 }

@Bean(name = "JmsTemplate")
public JmsTemplate provideJmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());        
    jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(Long.parseLong(env.getRequiredProperty(RECEIVE_TIMEOUT)));
    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Bean(name="MQConnectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

    if (factory == null) {
        factory = new MQXAConnectionFactory();
        try {
            factory.setHostName(env.getRequiredProperty(HOST));
            factory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getRequiredProperty(PORT)));            
            factory.setQueueManager(env.getRequiredProperty(QUEUE_MANAGER));
            factory.setChannel(env.getRequiredProperty(CHANNEL));
            factory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);  

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return factory;
}
```

The initial setting for the concurrency was '1-2' and I changed that to '10-15'. Did not affect performance.

The jmsCache was set to [3 (Consumer cache)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/constant-values.html#org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_CONSUMER), but no change there yet either.

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers
Kris

Comment: Could you tell us a few other things about your system? how many putters do you have? What is the rate of putting messages? How many concurrent getters do you have? Are there concurrent messages for them to process or can one getter keep up with the putter(s)? What else does each transaction have to do that could be useful to know in the full picture of your system's performance?

Comment: At this point in time the putters are simulated by the NFT team, using LoadRunner, with 100 tps. I had 2 instances of the container running, which means we were achieving 15 tps. I thought by setting the concurrency to '10-15' in DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory this would actually allow this many thread to process in parallel. The other part of the application transforms the json message from 1 format to another and sends an HTTP request to an Api which does the insert in the DB.

Comment: That's my understanding of setConcurrency too. How many getters do you see running against your queue? Try MQSC command `DISPLAY QSTATUS(q-name) IPPROCS`

Comment: I will provide some updates on that soon. It would seem that the issue is actually with the database connection pooling. There were thousands of sessions in the DB and we were expecting a few.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own post here. What we found out was that the problem was actually with our Database pooling not setup correctly in the first place.

But in order to increase the Listener count, I had to change my Spring integration adapter settings

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
        destination="requestQueue"
        channel="inputJsonConversionChannel" 
        connection-factory="cachingConnectionFactory" 
        error-channel="errorChannel"
        concurrent-consumers="${jms_adapter_concurrent_consumers}" />
```

Only when the concurrent-consumers is varied, does the number of listeners on the queue increase.